# Из секунд в дни - как?

Tags: c

```
 day = sec /
 hr = sec / 60 / 60;
 min = (sec - horas * 3600) / 60;
 seg = sec % 60;
```

Подскажите, как подключить дни?

Comment: @extazys, вы что, над UNIX TimeStamp извращаетесь что ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 день = 24 часа,
1 час = 60 минут, т.е. 1 день = 24 * 60 минут,
1 минута = 60 секунд, т.е. 1 день = 24 * 60 * 60 секунд,

т.е. в `X` секундах `X / ( 24 * 60 * 60 )` дней

> обычно нужно задание времени в опр.формате вроде dd:hh:mm:ss, а не просто кол-во минут или секунд

Логично! Тогда расчитываем остатки:

`D = 24 * 60 * 60`
`H = 60 * 60`
`M = 60`

`XD = X / D` дней
`XH = ( X - XD * D ) / H` часов
`XM = ( X - XD * D - XH * H ) / M` минут
`XS = ( X - XD * D - XH * H - XM * M )` секунд

Answer (score 2):

Дано 100 сек, найти: минуты, часы, дни.
Решение:

```
1min = 60 sec => 100 sec = 100/60
1 hour = 60 min = 60*60 sec => 100/60/60
1 day = 24 hour = 24*60 min = 24*60*60 sec = 100/24/60/60
```

не?

Comment: нет. А кто будет считать остатки?

Comment: @gecube а требуется?

Comment: Наверняка! Т.к. обычно нужно задание времени в опр.формате вроде dd:hh:mm:ss, а не просто кол-во минут или секунд...

Comment: @gecube а вдруг я сделаю в этом формате, а окажется, что не нужно было? Думаю следует недоделать, чем переделать. Тем более в ТЗ ничего о переводе в какой формат не сказано.